# how does webpack import from external url

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack to manage my react application. Now I want to import a dependency from this url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=gNO2wKVBNupZfafi0bl0sW3dIKqAHn4l">
```

traditionally I just put above code on my index.html file. But now how can I let webpack to load this url? And how my react js use that dependency?

when I launch webpack-dev-server, I will get below error:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'http://api.map.baidu.com/api'
```

Then I use little loader to load the url. Below is the javascript code to use loader:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import load from 'little-loader';

import './main.css';
import './component';
import Search from './search/search'

load('http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=gNO2wKVBNupZfafi0bl0sW3dIKqAHn4l', function(err){
    console.log('err:', err);
});

// document.body.appendChild(component());


ReactDOM.render(<Search />, document.getElementById('search'));
```

but I still got below error when launch webpack:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'http://api.map.baidu.com/api' in /Users/yzzhao/dev/react-demo/webpack_demo
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the future you should be able to use dynamic requires via `System.import`.
[Webpack 2](https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7) will support them natively.

```js
System.import('<url>')
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Loaded!');
  });
```

If you don't want to wait for it, you could use a script loading library.

**Example:**

Install:

```
npm install little-loader --save
```

Use:

```js
import load from 'little-loader';

load('<url>', (err) => {

})
```

**Or do it manually**

```js
function load(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  })
}

load('<url>')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Loaded!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Something went wrong!', err);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I followed the little-loader solution but is still not working. I have updated my post to give the code I used. Could you please take  a look and let me know whether I am using a correct way?

Comment: Did you try renaming `load` to `_load`? Maybe the keyword `load` is somehow reserved in your code.

Comment: I checked that when I am importing this dependency I got below error from the browser: It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.  How can I allow the browser to load it from an asynchronously?

Comment: Just try to use this URL instead: http://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?v=2.0&ak=gNO2wKVBNupZfafi0bl0sW3dIKqAHn4l&services=&t=20160401164342

Comment: I'm still struggling to get something closer to the fetch API or RequireJS API where the callback functions contain the instance

Comment: I followed the manual solution. Sure I have found and used this before as well. Love a full manual solution instead of installing new libraries constantly. +1.