# How to pull in remote react components via ECMA6 imports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

We want to separate our components into multiple projects and develop them separately. We do NOT want to pull them in as npm dependencies but rather, pull them in like remote "src" files in html. Is this possible?

`import MyCustomReactComponent from "http://foobar";`

Comment: Are you using any module bundler?

Comment: Webpack and babel at the moment.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36496242/218196

Comment: Yeah sadly it looks like you cant use System.import in the current version of web pack. The little-loader seems like a hack

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to pull in React components via npm?

Comment: The idea is that you can develop a component of your application, say for example, a chat box. You can then have a team that is responsible for creating and maintaining that chat box component. Now that team makes updates or fixes and deploys, when a user refreshes their browser they will get the updates. If we did it through node modules, then we would have to pull in the new version and redeploy for each component that gets changed.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/tonytonyjan/616022dce75f8e6c1603bbeb94ec46a4