# Is it possible to download and install JS-file (not NPM package) from NPM by URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, npm-install

Instead of adding `<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>` in the Index.html is it possible to add somehow URL for this JS-file in the package.json file (it is simple JS-file, not NPM package; and it is just URL for this JS-file, not GitHub URL) to NPM download and install it? The reason for it - there is a Webpack config which make some processing of all used JS-files. May be it is better to include all external JS-files (not NPM packages) into this Webpack processing

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using Webpack you may consider using something like [little-loader](https://github.com/walmartlabs/little-loader).

```
npm i little-loader --save
```

And then in your code

```
var load = require("little-loader");

load("https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js", function (err) {
  // ... your code ...
});
```

You can get some more inspiration from other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496242/how-does-webpack-import-from-external-url) as well.

In the Webpack [issues](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/240#issuecomment-40686135) I see the maintainer suggesting this approach:

```
var $script = require("scriptjs");
$script("https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js", function() {
  //.... your code ...
});
```

But that package looks a bit unmaintained.

At the end of the day, an option to consider is to just leave it in the HTML as well, it's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: I got it. You are talking about how to download external JS-file from JS-code. But how to make Webpack to get external JS-file and add it to the vendor.js?

Comment: The way I am aware (and it does **not** mean there aren't others...) is to make Webpack look for your scripts in `node_modules` or specify a path like `./../../../../my-script.js`. Sometimes it's just easier to publish your script on npm or fork an unpublished script from a Github repo and publish it yourself. If you are using Stripe though chances are there is a good reason why they want you to use the online version (see security updates). I wouldn't look for other ways to include that 3rd party script, I would just call it over the wire with one of the methods above.